# Couchbase async get or multi get

Tags: java, couchbase

I am trying to perform batch operation on couchbase using the java client. The version I use is 1.4.6 (latest I hope).

The problem is that both `client.getBulk()` and  async get produce timeout exception - even setting the timeout doesnt seem to help. see code below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    gets.add(client.asyncGet(keys[i]));
}    
for (GetFuture future : gets) {
    results.add(future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).toString());
}
```

Any idea why do I get this exception and how can I fix it?

```
Exception :
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
net.spy.memcached.internal.CheckedOperationTimeoutException: 
    Operation timed out. - failing node: ip-172-31-44-108.ec2.internal/172.31.44.108:11210
at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.get(OperationFuture.java:180)
at net.spy.memcached.internal.GetFuture.get(GetFuture.java:69)
```

Comment: Looks like, you're accessing couchbase on amazon which is configured to use aws internal ip address from app that isn't inside aws (so it doesn't resolve internal hostname or ip).

Comment: I am using couch on aws and i am using internal IP address, otherwise regular set/get wont work. they do. my only issue is with multi get

Answer (score 1):

Set the keepAliveTimeout while creating couchbase environment object. Set the timeout to 100000000

```
DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder().connectTimeout(couchbaseSetting.getConnectionTimeout())
            .keepAliveTimeout(couchbaseSetting.getKeepAliveTimeout())
            .queryTimeout(couchbaseSetting.getQueryTimeout())
            .socketConnectTimeout(couchbaseSetting.getSocketTimeout()).build()
```